# Java - catch/rethrow behavior

Tags: java, java-8

I have this piece of Java code.

```
void convertFile() { 

        try{
            ..... 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logError("Error in convertJsonFile", e);
            throw e;
        }finally{
            
            if (writer!=null) {
                writer.close();
                writer = null;
            }
            if (fos!=null) {
                fos.close();
                fos = null;
            }
            
            ms2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            logInfo(String.format("Time elapsed: %d seconds.", ((ms2-ms1)/1000)));
            logInfo("File conversion complete.");
            
        }
        
        return f + "_changed.xml";
}
```

The catch block logs and rethrows the Exception.
But it seems the finally block also throws a RuntimeException.

1. Will the finally block be executed if the catch block rethrows Exception as done here?
   If I remember correctly finally block will be executed even in this case.
2. OK if so... what will happen if we enter the catch block (it rethrows), then we enter the finally block, and the finally block also throws a RuntimeException at this line `writer.close();`  ?  Which exception will be thrown from this whole method - the rethrown one from the catch block, or the RuntimeException from the finally block?!
   I think the `RuntimeException` will be the final outcome of the method and we will never reach the line in the catch block which rethrows. Because I guess the line which rethrows is executed after the finally block. But I am not sure. I got really confused.

Could someone clear my doubts here?
Seems I have forgotten some of these details.

And I have no decent access to the logs, they are in Elastic/Kibana and access to them is a real pain.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, finally block will be executed
2. The exception from `finally` block will be thrown in this case. Thus, exception from `catch` block will be lost.

Comment: This is called exception masking. Could add that try with resources makes sure masking doesn’t happen.